# what database to use, and how install it when is being installed?

Tags: database, installation

I'm creating some software (restaurant and for store - 2 programs) I need to install the database at the same time as the software.

What database do you believe it's better? I would like to use Access 2007 but I have read this only could have 1 GB approx, and I wouldn't like to have to replace a database after only a small amount of time, losing my information (for example reports between 2 dates).

What database should I use and how do I install it, in the same moment my software is being installed too?

Comment: A restaurant with 1Gb of bookings will be very popular. I'm sure they could afford to upgrade :-)

Comment: On a serious point, I would consider which technology you're going to use to write this software, and find a *free* database to play with. I think most any database now will be able to handle your requirements

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't understand you very well but i think Mysql is better to begin :[Download](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/)
and you you can use phpmyadmin to to easy manage